# Trying to store session variable from result of SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-storage

I have tried everything from storing the query as a variable and using the fetch_array but it keeps just giving me the output "Array" when I try to print $_SESSION['permission']. I have no idea what to do please help.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
mysql_connect("localhost","",""); 
mysql_select_db("a"); 
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
    header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/whatever");
} 
if($_POST['submit'])
{
   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
   $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
   $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$name}' AND password = '{$pass}'"); 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT permission FROM users WHERE name = '{$name}' AND password = '{$pass}'");
   $permission = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   if(mysql_num_rows($mysql) < 1)
   {
     die("Password was incorrect!");
   } 
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "YES"; 
   $_SESSION['name'] = $name; 
   $_SESSION['permission'] = $permission;

   header ("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/whatever"); 
}  
echo "<form type='login.php' method='POST'>
Username: <br>
<input type='text' name='username'><br>
Password: <br>
<input type='password' name='password'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
</form>"; 
?>
```

Comment: What is outputted as `Array`? Where is `$row` being defined?

Comment: `$_SESSION['permission'] = $row;` where is $row ?

Comment: why are you using `header("Location: ")`?

Comment: your permission query is unfinished, probably you want to put `$result` in session

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the resultset using a loop,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//use each row value($row) as per your need
}
```

So, I believe, you want to achieve something like this,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT permission FROM users WHERE name = '{$name}' AND password                                 = {$pass}'"); 
$permission = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$name}' AND password =     '{$pass}'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($mysql) < 1)
{    
 die("Password was incorrect!");
} 

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "YES"; 
$_SESSION['name'] = $name; 
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
$_SESSION['permission' . $i] = $row;
$i++;
}
  header ("Location: "); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$row` is a result of a query you need to specify a column like `$_SESSION['permission'] = $row[column_name];`

Answer (score 0):

Just edited the POST part of your code. Remember that you must fetch the result and use the associative array to take the value of an specific column:

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
   $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
   $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$name}' AND password = {$pass}'");

   if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      die("Password was incorrect!");
   }

   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "YES"; 
   $_SESSION['name'] = $name; 
   $_SESSION['permission'] = $row['permission'];
   header ("Location: "); 
}
```

There is no need to run the query twice.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is not working. I am trying to get it to print out the $_SESSION['permission'] on another page and it keeps coming up completely blank.

Comment: Place a print_r($row); right before $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "YES"; and check if it has any data. Also, make sure you're using session_start() in your other page.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the row array to the `$_SESSION['permission']` variable so when you print it you get array.
Try using print_r on that array and you'll see what's in it.  Example: `print_r($_SESSION['permission']);`  Print cannot print an array.  Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to find out what's going on when you see this happen again.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php